# Angular Jest async test seems to overflow results from one test to another

Tags: angular, asynchronous, testing, jestjs

In Angular, using Jest we have 2 tests that test a method on a component class:

```js
  describe('checkEmailStatus', () => {
    it('set VERIFIED page design when email verification succeeds', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(authService, 'checkEmailVerification');
      await expect(component.checkEmailStatus()).resolves.toEqual(undefined);
      expect(authService.checkEmailVerification).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(component.pageDesign.key).toBe('verified');
    });

    it('set ERROR page design when email verification fails', async () => {
      const checkEmail = jest.spyOn(authService, 'checkEmailVerification');
      checkEmail.mockImplementation(() => {
        return Promise.reject(false);
      });
      await expect(component.checkEmailStatus()).resolves.toEqual(undefined);
      expect(authService.checkEmailVerification).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(component.pageDesign.key).toBe('error');
    });
  });
```

These tests have been running fine for a month. Nothing about this component has changed and neither have we changed Jest version (25.2.7) yet now the 2nd test complains that the method was called 3 times.

If I comment out the first test, the 2nd tests passes.

It seems that the first test is not tearing down correctly - is there something I need to do to force that? (I tried using the done() callback, but it made no difference)

**UPDATE**

This is the method under test:

```js
  async checkEmailStatus(): Promise<void> {
    this.isLoading = true;
    try {
      await this.authService.checkEmailVerification('');
      this.setPageDesign('verified');
      this.isLoading = false;
    } catch (error) {
      this.setPageDesign('error');
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

This is the stubbed authService:

```js
import {Observable, BehaviorSubject, of} from 'rxjs';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {mockUsers} from '../../../../mocks/user.mock';

// tslint:disable-next-line: completed-docs
function initStub() {
  const userId$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  return {
    userId$,
    checkEmailVerification(): Promise<boolean> {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
  };
}

export const authServiceStub = initStub();
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is the complete test file:

```js
import {AuthService} from 'src/app/shared/services/auth.service';
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {VerifyEmailComponent} from './verify-email.component';
import {SharedModule} from '../shared/shared.module';
import {getTranslocoModule} from '../transloco-testing.module';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import {environment} from 'src/environments/environment';
import {routerStub} from '../test/helpers/router.stub';
import {authServiceStub} from '../test/helpers/auth.service.stub';

fdescribe('VerifyEmailComponent', () => {
  let component: VerifyEmailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<VerifyEmailComponent>;
  let authService: AuthService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [VerifyEmailComponent],
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        getTranslocoModule({}),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
      ],
      providers: [routerStub, {provide: AuthService, useValue: authServiceStub}]
    }).compileComponents();
    authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(VerifyEmailComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('setPageDesign', () => {
    it('should set the correct design for VERIFY', () => {
      component.setPageDesign('verify');
      expect(component.pageDesign.key).toBe('verify');
    });

    it('should set the correct design for VERIFIED', () => {
      component.setPageDesign('verified');
      expect(component.pageDesign.key).toBe('verified');
    });

    it('should set the correct design for ERROR', () => {
      component.setPageDesign('error');
      expect(component.pageDesign.key).toBe('error');
    });

    it('should set the ERROR design for unknown status values', () => {
      component.setPageDesign('');
      expect(component.pageDesign.key).toBe('error');
    });
  });

  describe('checkEmailStatus', () => {
    it('set VERIFIED page design when email verification succeeds', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(authService, 'checkEmailVerification');
      await expect(component.checkEmailStatus()).resolves.toEqual(undefined);
      expect(authService.checkEmailVerification).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(component.pageDesign.key).toBe('verified');
    });

    it('set ERROR page design when email verification fails', async () => {
      const checkEmail = jest.spyOn(authService, 'checkEmailVerification');
      checkEmail.mockImplementation(() => {
        return Promise.reject(false);
      });
      await expect(component.checkEmailStatus()).resolves.toEqual(undefined);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(authService.checkEmailVerification).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(component.pageDesign.key).toBe('error');
    });
  });

  describe('onClickContinue', () => {
    // TODO: implement 2 tests for if/else cases of the button
    return undefined;
  });
});
```

This is the component code:

```js
import {TranslocoService, TRANSLOCO_SCOPE} from '@ngneat/transloco';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../shared/services/auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

// define static data to be used only by this component
interface PageDesign {
  icon: string;
  key: string;
}
const pageDesigns: PageDesign[] = [
  {
    icon: 'email-verified',
    key: 'verify'
  },
  {
    icon: 'email-verified',
    key: 'verified'
  },
  {
    icon: 'email-expired',
    key: 'error'
  }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'wn-verify-email',
  templateUrl: './verify-email.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./verify-email.component.scss'],
  providers: [{provide: TRANSLOCO_SCOPE, useValue: 'verifyEmail'}]
})
export class VerifyEmailComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  pageDesign: PageDesign;

  constructor(
    public translocoService: TranslocoService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  /**
   * Init
   */
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setPageDesign('verify');
    this.checkEmailStatus();
  }

  /**
   * Affects the current email data
   */
  setPageDesign(status: string): any {
    this.pageDesign = pageDesigns.find(
      emailDesign => emailDesign.key === status
    );
    if (!this.pageDesign)
      this.pageDesign = pageDesigns.find(
        emailDesign => emailDesign.key === 'error'
      );
  }

  /**
   * Check whether email address is verified
   */
  async checkEmailStatus(): Promise<void> {
    this.isLoading = true;
    try {
      await this.authService.checkEmailVerification('');
      this.setPageDesign('verified');
      this.isLoading = false;
    } catch (error) {
      this.setPageDesign('error');
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Click handler for the continue navigation button
   */
  onClickContinue(status: string) {
    if (status === 'verified')
      // TODO: use the continueURL from params and navigate to that
      console.error('continue url needed');
    else this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the complete test file and a snippet of your component code?

Comment: @PrinceIsNinja I have added the files. I also added your suggested answer, as you can see in the file...but now it complains it was called 2 times instead of 3, so a slight improvement!

Comment: Can you please provide mockImplementation in first test case as well like you did in second one. I am assuming that it is executing the actual one which is taking time. Else we need to debug it using debugger in test cases ...........  And also use jest.restoreAllMocks() in afterEach()

Comment: The first test case is definitely calling the stub method, which returns true. If I do a mockImplementation in the first test, resolving to true, the results is the same (2 calls received instead of 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reset the spy count, either reset the mocks inside the test case or inside the afterEach block. It will reset the number of times spy called.

```
afterEach(() => {    
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});
```

You ca read more about it here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearallmocks

Hope it will help you!

There are number of links that will be helpful for you:

[Use of spyOn and read its NOTE very carefully.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

[Use of mockRestore](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrestore)

Comment: Thanks for your help, that didn't work BUT if I put `jest.clearAllMocks();` at the start of the 2nd test, it works!

Comment: Great, not sure why it did not work in afterEach. afterEach is a method call after each test case. Happy to help!